# Does my Thinkpad T60 chipset output a composite video signal on one of the output leads

Tags: video, thinkpad, tv

I am not a tech. How can I find out this information?

EDIT: Please someone answer this. I don't really want to accept my own answer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much search, I think I understand this.

**#  Flexible display support
    * Dual integrated dual-link DVI transmitters
          o DVI 1.0 compliant / HDMI interoperable and HDCP ready***

I believe that the answer to my question above is "No", although I still don't understand enough to be completely clear.
I believe this fragment from the T60 site states that my Thinkpad T60 sends a digital signal out to both the monitor and the 2nd monitor port.

If I am right, I just need a cable with the right connectors on it and a digital TV an then I can display videos from my computer on TV.

Please correct me if I am wrong.
Regards.