# How to connect laptop to CRT TV (audio and video)?

Tags: laptop, video, crt

My [laptop](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks/Versatile_Performance/K43SJ/#specifications) has VGA and hdmi out. The graphics card is GT520m. My TV has :

- 3 RCA input
- 3 RCA output
- 3+2 Component input

I want to connect laptop to TV for watching videos. Please suggest an economical solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not planning on watching HD video, I'd get an active conversion box, such as this one
http://www.eeepcssd.com/product_info.php?currency=USD&products_id=41

Comment: By the sound of the product description "Exports VGA signal to VGA monitor", I don't think this will help get his laptop to display on a TV.

Comment: Woops. You're right. Wrong link! I meant this!
http://www.eeepcssd.com/product_info.php?currency=USD&products_id=41

Comment: These converters are little expensive. Will this work http://www.dealextreme.com/p/vga-to-component-cable-5-ft-4681 and can anybody tell me that my card has tv-out ?

Comment: Your graphics adapter does not have TV out.  I think the last nVidia card that had it was the GeForce 9500GT.  You need to use somekind of VGA converter.  A passive cable or adapter cannot convert VGA to composite or component video.

Comment: It is little expensive but I guess an active converter is the only solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Serious, the component cable *may* work, but [my warning below](http://superuser.com/questions/368977/how-to-connect-laptop-to-crt-tv-audio-and-video#comment511601_368982). The converter boxes are actually not that expensive (all things considered). They can be had for under $14. I explain their benefits [here](http://superuser.com/questions/46462/laptop-video-out-to-tv/441921#441921).

Comment: Component is just RGB with some inversion, addition, and subtraction applied. And assuming it's an HD TV, it will handle HD resolutions just fine. Go with the active VGA to component converter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get an adapter.  Here's a [link for a VGA to Component 3 adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00213KFHW) ($10.99) and here's one for a [VGA to RCA adapter](http://www.overstock.com/Electronics/Eforcity-VGA-to-S-Video-3-RCA-Adapter/4611948/product.html?cid=202290&kid=9553000357392&track=pspla&adtype=pla&kw=%7Bkeyword%7D) ($0.99).

Comment: Will the second one work. There are many bad reviews. I have read somewhere that it requires TV out from graphics card( I don't know whether my card supports it)

Comment: As far as the quality goes, I suppose that's what you get for 99 cents.  I would think the VGA-to-Component one would fare a lot better, though.  I used to do this with one of my desktops when I had an old ATI card with an S-video out...but it doesn't sound like that's an option for you.

Comment: Serious is correct, your video-adapter **must** support tv-out via the VGA connector (seemingly quite rare), otherwise the second adapter will not work. The first one is better for the OP and should presumably work, but even that it *may* not be compatible according to the warning on the page: *This cable requires a video converter or output device that can process a YPbPr signal through an HD15 (VGA) port.*

Comment: And for the first adapter, your video adapter must support component out on the VGA connector, also exceedingly rare. You need an active adapter.